# Why is the infinite dimensional vector space with only finitely many nonvanishing components incomplete?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Define a complex vector space $V$ such that any element $\{a_i\}=(a_1,a_2,\dots)\in V$ has only finitely many components $a_i\ne 0$. The inner product is defined as

$$(\{a_i\},\{b_j\})=\sum_i^\infty a_i^* b_i$$

Can we find an example to show that $V$ is incomplete?

One example I have is this sequence $\langle i\rangle=(0,0,\dots,1/i,0,0,\dots)$, i.e., the $i$-th element of the sequence has only one nonzero component, which is the $i$-th component and whose value is $1/i$. But this sequence should converge to $0$....

I need help! Thanks!

Comment: Try summing that sequence.

Comment: @nate eldredge I tried before posting the question, but that won't be a Cauchy sequence. right?

Comment: It is Cauchy. Hint: $\sum 1/n^2$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $\{a^{(k)}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ where $a^{(k)} = \{a_{i}^{(k)}\}_{i=1}^\infty$, and we define
$$
a_i^{(k)} = 
\begin{cases}
1/i & i \leq k\\
0 & i > k
\end{cases}
$$
So, we have
$$
a^{(1)} = \{1,0,0,0,0,\dots\}\\
a^{(2)} = \{1,1/2,0,0,0,\dots\}\\
a^{(3)} = \{1,1/2,1/3,0,0,\dots\}\\
\vdots
$$
Why is this a Cauchy sequence in $V$?  How do we know that the sequence doesn't converge?

Comment: Yes, I realise this sequence is not a Cauchy in $V$, but what is the example needed?

Comment: This is the example needed.  The limit is not in $V$

Comment: Consider the norm of $a^{(i)}-a^{(j)}$ with $i>j$ (in your notation): $||a^{(i)}-a^{(j)}||^2=1/(j+1)^2+1/(j+2)^2+\cdots+1/i^2<(i-j)/(j+1)^2$. As long as $i>>j$, this norm can be huge! So this is not a Cauchy sequence. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes; that upper bound is correct but not tight.  Note that $\sum_i \frac{1}{i^2}$ converges, so the Cauchy criterion holds.

Comment: If it really bothers you, you can use $a_i = 1/2^i$ instead.